# Match a space that is not at the end of the line

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match all spaces and convert to escaped spaces, but only those which do not occur at the end of a line, so far I've tried `/\ !$/\\\ /g` to and general button mashing around that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this regular expression `(?m)( +)(?!$)`

`(?m)` regex option multyLine

`( +)` > 0 spaces

`(?!$)` is not end of line